# How to stop specific thread in multithreads and to destroy all variables and objects created in specific thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm developing a client-server program. I use C# programming language and .net framework 4. At there, whenever new client is connected to the server, the server will create new thread to process each client. If one of the client is disconnected, the thread which controls this disconnected client will also be stopped (killed). I don't know how to stop this specific thread among multiple threads. The pseudo-code of my program will be like that:

**Server Side Program:**

```
Thread t;
private void form1_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    startserver();
}

void startserver()
{
     t = new Thread(waitclientconnection);
     t.start();
}

void waitclientconnection()
{
    //namedpipeserverconnection code
    //waitforclientconnection

    if (clientOne is connected)
    {    
         startserver(); //create new thread to wait connection for next client
    }

    //object and variable that created within the thread
    Clientprofile cp = new Clientprofile(); 
    String clientstate = "....";

    if (clientOne sends "close" message)
    {
    //the thread that controls ClientOne will be killed   <-- This is the point that I would like to solve
    }
}
```

I confessed that the program is a little complex but currently I have only this way to implement my program. I found some solutions that suggested to declare Boolean variable to control the thread stop or running using while looping. But in my program, this way can stop the whole thread and cannot able to create new threads for new connected clients. Moreover, I also want to know whether the variables and objects created in each specific thread can also be destroy from the memory when this thread is stopped. Imagine that if hundred clients were connected within one hour and currently only 10 clients are in connection. I only want to keep only objects and variables in memory for only these 10 clients. The question is complex but I'm sure all of you can able to solve and give any suggestions. Really hope for your suggestions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thread that receives the close message is the one that should be 'killed', right?

So just make sure the code stops and returns normally.
Do not call `Thread.Abort()` or anything, that will make a mess.

```
void waitclientconnection()
{
    if (clientOne is connected)
    {    
         startserver(); //create new thread to wait connection for next client
    }

    while (keepGoing)
    {
        ...

        if (clientOne sends "close" message)
        {
             keepGoing = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: really helpful...thanks u...but it has one more question "can objects and variables be able to destroyed from the memory at once this thread is killed"...thanks again

Comment: Objects will get "destroyed from memory" automatically by the Garbage Collector as needed (not typically asap) as long as they're not referenced anywhere else. [See Garbage Collection (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xy59wtx.aspx)

Comment: No, memory cannot be cleared 'at once' . But that's not a problem. Resources should be managed in a `using() {}` block.

Answer (score 1):

Try refactoring your code such that you have a single listener thread that spawns off client threads when it gets a connection.  Each of those client threads should be able to end themselves when the time is right.  Also, you should probably set the client threads' `IsBackground` properties to `true`, so they won't prevent the server from exiting.

The way you are doing it right now is probably workable, too, but seems more complex than necessary.